# Embed Google Chrome in Windows Applications

Tags: windows, api, google-chrome, activex, embed

Is there any way to embed Google Chrome engine in our Windows applications to show HTML pages like the time we can use IE ActiveX in our programs?

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know this existed, but [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/).

Comment: There is also this one: http://awesomium.com

Comment: awesomium is not opernsourced tho , i am thinking to make something like that based on cef

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is open source.
Download the source and implement the renderer